# ssh/ping できない centos7 host is down

Tags: macos, centos, ssh

お世話になっております。

数時間前から急にssh接続ができなくなりました。 
環境は以下のとおりです。

接続先：vpsサーバー-Centos7 
接続元：Mac OS 10.11.6

```
localhost:.ssh user$ ssh -i id_rsa username@vpsserver -vvv
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to vps_ip_add [vps_ip_add] port 22.
```

pingではrequest_timeoutとhost is downが返されます。

直前にしていた作業としては、

1. テスト環境構築のためvagrantを立ち上げ。
2. hostsファイルを変更 
   [vps_ip_add] xxx.com => [vps_ip_add] yyy.com
3. 公開ディレクトリの権限をいじった
   ぐらいなのですが何か解決策ありますでしょうか。

ちなみに関係あるかわかりませんがシリアルコンソールでVPSのip aを実行したところ、xxx.xx.x.xxx/23となっておりました。 
今まで23だったかわからないのですがあまり見たことがないので。。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/65514

Comment: マルチポスト先で自己解決されたようですが、こちらにもその旨を書くのが筋では？